# С# Имя из названия переменной гетера/сеттера

Tags: c#

Есть какие идеи как получить имя в случае, если свойство статическое:

```
public static class xWrapper
{
    public static Object TestName
    {
        get { return X(nameof(???)); } // вот тут надо получить имя "TestName"
    }
}
```

Comment: Так а что мешает просто написать "TestName"?

Comment: религиозные соображения мешают :) если таких строк 200+ Очевидно что рефлексией, но в статичных методах нету `this`, так что откуда начинать для меня не очевидно..

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206023/how-to-get-current-property-name-via-reflection

Comment: отредактировал название

Comment: nameof(TestName)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Решение для .NET 4.5+:

```
public static string GetPropertyName([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    return propertyName;
}

public static Object TestName
{
    get {
        return X(GetPropertyName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Для 4.0 тоже сработает, если объявить класс самостоятельно, т. к. это фича компилятора: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896300/6766879

Comment: О! отличный подход, спасибо

Answer (score 6):

1.`nameof(PropertyName)`

---

2.Даный код вернет название проперти в геттере и сеттере без прямого указывания названия :

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Replace("set_", "").Replace("get_", "");
```

Код не очень красивый, зато сработает.

---

3.Третий путь -- подобен второму: вытягивать из стектрейса эту же информацию и подниматся на 1 уровень вверх:

```
public static class Props
{
    public static string CurrPropName => 
         (new StackTrace()).GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name.Replace("set_", "").Replace("get_", "");

    public static string CurrMethodName => 
        (new StackTrace()).GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
}
```

И если ты из проперти вызовешь `Props.PropName` оно вернет тебе название самой проперти. Если вызовешь `Props.CurrMethodName` -- даст название метода в котором ты сейчас находишся.

PS: но мне больше нравится решение MSDN.WhiteKnight

Comment: 3 сработает только в Debug-режиме, в Release не гарантируется

Comment: И ваши предложения оригинальные и имеют право на жизнь, но я тоже склоняюсь к реализации MSDN.WhiteKnight